# Eclipse libGDX can't run as Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I have a libGDX project in Eclipse which of course uses Gradle. When I try to run the AndroidLauncher, I don't get an option to run it as an Android Project. I only get two options which are `Gradle Build` and `Gradle Build...` (Same thing with "..."). The odd thing is that if I first right click on the `AndroidLauncher.java` and click anything and try to run the project, then it works. It works until I change the core code class. Then it only has the same two options again. How can I solve this and always run it as an Android Project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than running the `AndroidLauncher.java`, running the **project folder** solved the problem. It now always runs as an Android Project.